# Keyboard on Samsung device does not re appear after it is closed

Tags: android

I have very strange problem.

The keyboard does not show up after the user is closes it. when user enters the activity the keyboard is shown, but if the user is closing it by using the back button, the keyboard does not came up again !

it happened only on some devices. 
on my Xiaomi device it is working OK, keyboard is shown when focus is changed, but on Samsung A8 device the keyboard is not shown again.

This is what i have in the manifest XML:

```
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

i have tried to add the following code:

```
        playerGivenName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                getActivity().getWindow()
                        .setSoftInputMode(
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

is it something wrong in my application or in the device setup?

Comment: Please, Who can help me with this issue?